# Making the article title the h1 tag joomla 3.2

Tags: joomla, page-title

I changed the standard settings of my joomla page a little, I made the article title the h1 heading on the front end and changed the settings so that the menu title does not show up. To make the article title an h1 I used a extension called header tags.

The problem was that the word "Article" showed up on every page (as the h1 tag) that did not have a menu item linked to it, i.e. all the pages that were linked to the rest of the site through another article. I resolved this with the approach listed here: http://blog.cyburg.eu/2012/02/27/fixed_suppression_of_name_articles_jglobal_articles_in_joomla_bug/

After that the h1 heading "Article" was gone, however, the article title was not made the h1 tag. Can anyone tell me how to make the article title (which is set as a h2 by standard) an h1?

Here is the code that makes up the front end:

```
<div class="page-header">
   <h1>  </h1>
</div>

<div class="page-header">
   <h2>the articles title</h2>
</div>
```

What strikes me is that the h1 tags are still there...
I am using joomla 3.2

Comment: Why don't you just do a layout override and change the second part of your code to h1 tags?  In fact  I think you just need to override one of the jlayouts.

Comment: @Elin, I am not advanced enough to specifically understand what you mean. Could you explain in a little more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php to the html folder of your template ... 
templates/templatename/html/com_content/article/default.php.

Then change

around lines 45 and 56 to

.

And  you can cut out the whole h1 block that you aren't using at around line 29.

Comment: This partially worked, I left lines 45 to 56 as they were and only took out the whole h1 block at line 29. This did the job, the plug-in remained enabled.
However, the problem I have since I made these changes is that I get "span class=" on my front end at the very bottom, does this have anything to do with the changes?

Comment: Also, if I were to change my mind again and want the code that I deleted back, where can I get it from? or do I just need to delete the override and create it again?

Comment: Delete and create again. It's hard to know where that is coming from but carefully look through the layouts -- looking at the generated source may help.